# JSON to Google sheets using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to transfer the values from JSON to a Google Sheet.

The values in JSON file are something like this `{"someone_name1@gmail.com": 4, "someone_name2.com": 4}` and they keep updating in the different run of the script. However, I am getting an error when its trying to put the value in the sheet.

```
    sheet4.update_cells(1, 1, results)
TypeError: update_cells() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Here is the code below. Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? I tried researching this but not able to find a suitable answer. As I am new to coding and python, I am unable to figure this one out. Any help appreciated. :)

```
# all functions imported
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
from collections import Counter

# login & open sheet sheets
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('myfile-b16b15370c5b.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet4 = client.open('Dashboard').worksheet('Sheet4')  # Open the spreadsheet

counter_file_path = "counter.json"

with open(counter_file_path, "r") as f:
    email_stats = json.load(f)

results = []
for key in email_stats:
    results.append([key, email_stats[key]])

sheet4.update_cells(1, 1, results)
```

Comment: What happens if you try `sheet4.update_cell(1, 1, 'Bingo!')`?

Comment: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#top-level `update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='RAW')`. You need to pass a list of cells so something like `update_cells([1, 1], results)`. Although your range seems to be one cell only so you may as well use `update_cell()`

Comment: Hi, @NomadMonad for reference I have just used 1 cell. Considering there are various entries in the JSON file. It will update to a range of cells so used `update_cells()` I tried running the code as mentioned and I am getting this error now `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'row'`

@Hoenie yes the string value updates correctly

Comment: Looks like you need to pass a list of `Cell` objects. You could either instantiate the objects yourself or you could get the range like the example in the doc. `cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:C7')`

Comment: Yes, tried doing this `sheet4.update_cells([cell_list], results)` and `sheet4.update_cells(cell_list, results)`. For the 1st one its giving me an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'` for the 2nd one `gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at \'value_input_option\' (TYPE_ENUM), ......` Its a very long error code

Comment: I presume it's something to do with the values you are trying to write. Maybe they are greater than the number of cells you are trying to write to?

Comment: Well, the values in the JSON file are `{"someone_name1@gmail.com": 4, "someone_name2@gmail.com": 4}` and this list will increase depending upon the data. So shouldn't it ideally be just 2 columns?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? I can understand about the sample input. It's `{"someone_name1@gmail.com": 4, "someone_name2.com": 4}`. But I cannot understand about the sample output you expect from your question. So can I ask you about the sample output you expect when your sample input value is used?

Comment: So I have [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xty5b3utc94v4tl/Annotation%202020-04-19%20074151.png?dl=0) is the output that I am looking for. I have a list of emails in google sheet. I want the counter figures to display in front of them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your sample input value, `{"someone_name1@gmail.com": 4, "someone_name2.com": 4}` is used. In your sample output image, the counters of `someone_name1@gmail.com` and `someone_name2@gmail.com` are `2` and `3`, respectively. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about this logic for retrieving this output from the input values. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: So the JSON file saves countup of the successful email that is sent to a particular email ID in different script run. These values get reset based on a condition. Hence the output is shown as the one shown in the image. And from these values another condition get executed which is driven from the Google Sheet. Hence looking for a way to input them in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.